# How do I display the user's Computer username/name in a Label?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to make a label, that contains the user's computer name.

For example, if I created a login form, and if you got the username and password right, it would redirect you to a form, which in the form's label would contain data from the username TextBox. However, I don't have a login form for mine, so how do you make a Label display the user's computer name? I'm using this code at the moment by the way:

```
Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click
  Label1.Text = System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.ComputerName
End Sub
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: the name is supposed to 'appear' on label click? I guess not, so your 'label1.text' line should work by itself...

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44234447/how-to-pass-value-between-forms-to-make-a-label-display-their-computer-name

Comment: You seem to be using two StackOverflow accounts to post identical questions. Please stop doing this.